# Skewness and central moment

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have distribution which I want to calculate the third order moment function of my distribution. I got confused what is different between `Moment` third order and skewness and which one are correct for my purpose.

this is what I am writing?

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 2.5]];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.5],];
i = Abs[Moment[data1, 3]];
i1 = Abs[Moment[data2, 3]];
```

or I can

```
Skewness[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2.5, 2.5]]]?
```

Comment: Which third order moment? Raw, Central or other? These aspects of the question are not related to _Mathematica_.

Comment: @wolfies   Is it  right that the second, third and fourth central moments can be expressed in terms of the raw moments: which here i need the third one which is skewness. Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"which one are correct for my purpose" Depends, what is your purpose?

```
SeedRandom[1234];

dist1 = NormalDistribution[2, 2.5];
```

data must have more than one sample. Using sample size of `100`

```
data1 = RandomVariate[dist1, 100];

dist2 = NormalDistribution[1, 0.5];

data2 = RandomVariate[dist2, 100];

{Style[#, 14, Bold], v = ToExpression[#]; Moment[v, 3], CentralMoment[v, 3], 
     Skewness[v]} & /@ {"dist1", "data1", "dist2", "data2"} //
  Prepend[#, 
    Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
     {"", Moment[3], CentralMoment[3], 
      Skewness}] & //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:** [`Skewness`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skewness.html) is a "normalized" (dimensionless) third central moment.

```
SeedRandom[1234];

dist1 = NormalDistribution[Quantity[2, "Meter"], Quantity[2.5, "Meter"]];

data1 = RandomVariate[dist1, 100];

dist2 = NormalDistribution[Quantity[1, "Meter"], Quantity[0.5, "Meter"]];

data2 = RandomVariate[dist2, 100];

{Style[#, 14, Bold], v = ToExpression[#]; Moment[v, 3], CentralMoment[v, 3], 
     Skewness[v]} & /@ {"dist1", "data1", "dist2", "data2"} // 
  Prepend[#, 
    Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"", Moment[3], CentralMoment[3], Skewness}] & // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon   Thanks for your help , My purpose is calculate the third order moment function for a l distribution which its mean is not zero. I am little get confused why the skewness and third order of central moment are different? should they be same?

Comment: @Mreza - As stated in the documentation for [`Skewness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skewness.html), "Skewness[ ... ] is equivalent to CentralMoment[ ..., 3]/CentralMoment[ ..., 2]^(3/2)".